# What is the maximum transfer rate of Firebase Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database for my android app. I wanted to know that is there any technical limit of Firebase realtime database for updating a node and listening to it. Say one client is updating data at a node at 5 seconds and as it is realtime then the listener client will receive this changed data very fast.

There maybe many clients connected to database who may upload a node at 5 secs, so is there any limit or such a fast updating of node will **overload Firebase server**? As in API reference there is a exception [FirebaseTooManyRequestsException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) or shall I **decrease updating speed** from 5 seconds to 10 seconds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase for free the you are allowed to make upto 100 simultaneous connections at a time.Or else if you go for paid versions BLAZE or FLAME you can make unlimited connections...Link provided below for reference...https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: I am aware of connections limit. I am asking about real time database limit for updating speed of a node.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your plan of selection the speed works for more details for limits of firebase database you can visit here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits